# Rate limiting Django admin login with Nginx to prevent dictionary attack

Tags: django, nginx, admin, rate-limiting

I'm looking into the various methods of rate limiting the Django admin login to prevent dictionary attacks.

One solution is explained here: http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/

However, I would prefer to do the rate limiting at the web server side, using Nginx.

Nginx's `limit_req` module does just that - allowing you to specify the maximum number of requests per minute, and sending a 503 if the user goes over: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule

Perfect! I thought I'd cracked it until I realised that Django admin's login page is not in a consistent place, eg /admin/blah/ gives you a login page at that URL, rather than bouncing to a standard login page.

So I can't match on the URL. Can anyone think of another way to know that the admin page was being displayed (regexp the response HTML?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all: to secure the django admin a little bit, i always use a url for the admin different to /admin/ a good idea would be to deploy the admin as a second application on another domain or subdomain

you can limit the requests per minute to the whole webapp via IPTABLES/NETFILTER.  a tutorial how this is done can be found at [debian administrator](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html). this is an example how to secure the ssh-port, but you can use the same technique for http.

You can use NginxHttpLimitZone module to limit the number of simultaneous connections for the assigned session or as a special case, from one IP address. Edit nginx.conf:

from [www.cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html)

```
### Directive describes the zone, in which the session states are stored i.e. store in slimits. ###
### 1m can handle 32000 sessions with 32 bytes/session, set to 5m x 32000 session ###
       limit_zone slimits $binary_remote_addr 5m;

### Control maximum number of simultaneous connections for one session i.e. ###
### restricts the amount of connections from a single ip address ###
        limit_conn slimits 5;
```

The above will limits remote clients to no more than 5 concurrently "open" connections per remote ip address.

Answer (score 1):

bmaeser is right, you should run admin in a separate instance (ie separate domain/subdomain/port).

You might also be interested in [django-sentinel](https://github.com/s29/django-sentinel), which does dynamic greylisting of suspicious ip addresses/networks using memcached and auto-blacklists repeat offenders.